# facebook feed metadata is not returned

Tags: facebook-graph-api, metadata, feed

I am using FB Graph API to retrieve feed information. I would like to get metadata from the feed but I somehow cannot.

here is the url i use to get feed info:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?metadata=1&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN

and here is the facebook example:

https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435?metadata=1&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN

so why in the former I have no metadata but in the latter I have?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't getting the `metadata` because you have already selected a feed (Profile feed (Wall) - `/feed` ). To get `metadata` of the available feeds about yourself (`/me`) remove the `/feed`:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?metadata=1&access_token=YOURACCESSTOKEN